# image-checkboxes in repeatet part

Tags: html, css, image, checkbox, repeat

I saw in another post how to use custom images instead of checkboxes. That's nice in web and important for finger-use on smartphones.

I tried to use that in a repeated part in a form:

```
<?php do { ?>


    <div id="one"><?php echo $row_Articles['article_name']; ?>
    </div>

  <div>

    <style>
  input[type=checkbox] {
    display:none;
  }

  input[type=checkbox] + label
   {
       background: url(../images/icons/unchecked.png) no-repeat;
       height: 28px;
       width: 28px;
       display:inline-block;
       padding: 0 0 0 0px;
   }


 input[type=checkbox] + label:hover
    {
        background: url(../images/icons/hover.png) no-repeat;
        height: 28px;
        width: 28px;
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    }


   input[type=checkbox]:checked + label
    {
        background: url(../images/icons/checked.png) no-repeat;
        height: 28px;
        width: 28px;
        display:inline-block;
        padding: 0 0 0 0px;
    }
    </style>

      <input name="auswahl[]" type="checkbox" id="auswahl[]" value="<?php echo $row_Articles['article_id']; ?>,<?php echo $row_Articles['article_name']; ?>"><label for="auswahl[]"></label>
    </div>


  <?php } while ($row_Articles = mysql_fetch_assoc($Articles)); ?>
```

The unchecked and hover pictures are working well. But when I click on a image-button, always and only the first checkbox change to checked-picture. In the same way I can uncheck only the first row, but by clicking on any picture-checkbox. I searched for hours, with no results. Does anybody see my mistake?

Thank you for helping me!

Comment: What html does that php generate? This is, or seems to be, a [tag:html] and [tag:css] question; the php is likely irrelevant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are setting each and every checkbox to have the same `id`. As per the HTML specification an element's id value needs to be unique, so where you implement the checkbox you need to do something like:

```
<input name="auswahl[]" type="checkbox" id="auswahl_<?php echo $row_Articles['article_id']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row_Articles['article_id']; ?>,<?php echo $row_Articles['article_name']; ?>"><label for="auswahl_<?php echo $row_Articles['article_id']; ?>"></label>
```

This will work as long as each `$row_Articles['article_id']` is unique, otherwise you will need to add an incrementing integer to your do/while loop and use that for creating the `id` attribute of the input and the `for` attribute of the label.

Also, you do not need to add the content of the `<style>` tag in each loop, it only needs to be included once.

Comment: Thank you winterblood! That works fine. Now I see it and I learned something. You are my hero! jutee